# Accessing datasets for AutoML Vision API

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have found GET request url for getting datasets from documentation https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/reference/rest/ as below:
https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/Concreting (Concreting is dataset name)

In response I am getting  404 file not found error so there is something missing in url.

can you please provide me correct documentation link which I should refer?

Answer (score 2):

`{name}` needs to be the fully qualified identifier of the dataset in format `projects/{project-id}/locations/us-central1/datasets/{dataset-id}`.

Dataset IDs are not unique across projects so you need to specify your Project ID in the REST endpoint URL.

You can find an example in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/datasets#delete-dataset) using the analogous `DELETE` method.

In your case, this should be something like:

```sh
projectId=$(gcloud config get-value project)    
curl -X GET \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://automl.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/$projectId/locations/us-central1/datasets/Concreting
```